# Django-adaptors: How to use correctly the Update meta option

Tags: python, django, csv

Thanks for being here reading my question.

I am doing a webshop for a photography company and I need to read a csv file to update the products on the database. I am using [django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to iterate the file and save the information, now is working good by the first time, but if run the command again the app creates new objects instead of overwrite the existing.

The problem is that I don't know what is the correct way to use the Update meta option. (You can see it in [the documentation](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#meta-options))

This is the code that I have right now:

```
from models import Type, Vendor, Product
from adaptor.model import CsvModel
from adaptor import fields as adaptor_fields

# Prepare functions here, but are not relevant information

class csv(CsvModel):
    mfr_code = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    main_photo_url = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    name = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    product_url = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    vendor = adaptor_fields.CharField(prepare=get_or_create_vendor)
    type = adaptor_fields.CharField(prepare=get_or_create_type)
    subtype = adaptor_fields.IgnoredField()
    description = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    specs = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    tags = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    stock = adaptor_fields.IntegerField(prepare=get_stock_value)
    price = adaptor_fields.IntegerField(prepare=format_usd)

    class Meta:
        delimiter = ','
        dbModel = Product
        update = {
            'keys': ['D1 Basic Kit 250/500', 'D1 Studio Kit 250/250']
        }
```

As you can see above I have the dictionary with the 'keys' value, but I don't know how to define the list of 'natural keys' and I am getting a KeyError exception when trying to run the command.

Can someone explain me what is the method to do it the right way?

Thanks for answering.

Cristian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'keys' should point out to a field name, not a field value. I guess 'D1 Basic Kit 250/500' or 'D1 Studio Kit 250/250' are names, then you should have something like:

```
class csv(CsvModel):
    mfr_code = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    main_photo_url = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    name = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    product_url = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    vendor = adaptor_fields.CharField(prepare=get_or_create_vendor)
    type = adaptor_fields.CharField(prepare=get_or_create_type)
    subtype = adaptor_fields.IgnoredField()
    description = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    specs = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    tags = adaptor_fields.CharField()
    stock = adaptor_fields.IntegerField(prepare=get_stock_value)
    price = adaptor_fields.IntegerField(prepare=format_usd)

    class Meta:
        delimiter = ','
        dbModel = Product
        update = {
            'keys': ['name']   # or mfr_code, main_photo_url, etc..., price
        }
```